# Combining rows with same data into one and add the numbers together

Tags: mysql, report

we currently have this in our table. we want to pull a report so it shows the following

(TPT = Total PLaying time; TP = Times played)

```
Name          | media time |     Date        |  TPT  | TP    
--------------+------------+-----------------+-------+---
Advertise.jpg | 10:20      | 2014/09/15 9:15 | 10:19 | 1    
Advertise.jpg | 10:20      | 2014/09/15 9:20 | 10:19 | 1    
Advertise.jpg | 10:20      | 2014/09/15 9:25 | 10:19 | 1    
Advertise.jpg | 10:20      | 2014/09/15 9:30 | 10:19 | 1
```

I want to combine all those rows into 1 but it must update the numeric fields. so should look like.

```
Advertise.jpg | 20 | 40:40 | 4 |
```

It's like a Point of sale report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write sql like this:

### **QUERY**

```
select name,sum(tpt),sum(tp) 
from table 
where name='Advertise.jpg' 
group by name
```